# boost::this_thread::get_id not returning id during exit() call

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have a fairly simple C++ application with a couple of threads in it - the main thread, and a worker thread.  The worker thread waits for packets sent over a network, and on receiving a disconnection, calls exit( 0 ).

This causes the destructor for the class responsible for the thread to run.  This destructor would usually be run from the main thread, and causes the worker thread (if running) to stop, and then calls join to wait for it to stop.  Here's the code for the destructor:

```
if( m_thread.get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id() )
{
    return;
}
if ( m_thread.joinable() )
{
    m_runThread = false;
    m_thread.join();
}
```

My problem is, that the line

```
if( m_thread.get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id() )
```

is returning false, even though I can tell from debugging that this code is definitely being run on the thread referenced by m_thread.

Having looked into this a bit more, boost::this_thread::get_id() is returning an id of 0 at this point.  However, the visual studio debugger and win32 API function GetCurrentThreadId are both still able to correctly identify the thread id.

Can anyone provide an explanation for this?  Is boost::this_thread not supported properly during application shutdown,  perhaps because it's been destructed already at this point?

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `exit` in a thread! This function exits the whole process not just the thread. Just return from the thread function.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that was my solution to the problem.  I wasn't looking for a solution though - I was asking if anyone knew why boost::this_thread::get_id doesn't seem to function properly under these circumstances.

Comment: @obmarg Even though your object instance still lives, the thread does not, and so `get_id` will return some default value.

Comment: OK, although is it possible for the thread to be dead even though I can still see it's full stack trace in the debugger at the point this code is being run?

Comment: @obmarg The stack trace is that of the call to the destructor, it's impossible to say what thread a stack trace belongs to by just looking at it. Print thread ids when creating threads, and in the debugger you should be able to see what thread the program stops in and compare to what you printed earlier.

Comment: Maybe I'm incorrect, but it seems fairly reasonable to me that if the stack trace for the destructor begins with all the functions called by the worker thread, then the destructor is probably running on the worker thread.  I've checked using the thread ID's as you suggested, which confirms my suspicions.  The win32 API is able to correctly return the thread id, but boost::this_thread::get_id is not.  Think I'll update my question with some of this information.

Answer (score 1):

`exit(0)` forces all threads to exit. The thread referenced by `m_thread` may have been destroyed when you calling `m_thread.get_id()`.

Comment: Perhaps, but the stack trace displayed by the debugger at the point the destructor is run displays the entire stack trace for the thread referenced by m_thread.  Would that be possible if m_thread had been destroyed at this point?